# Heroku + rails, rake db migrate worked locally and failed on heroku...

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, migration, heroku, rake

I'm changing the scale on a column like so....

```
change_column :options, :size, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 8
```

It's working locally, however when running it heroku it's throwing the error...

```
PGError: ERROR:  numeric field overflow
DETAIL:  A field with precision 8, scale 8 must round to an absolute value less than 1.
: ALTER TABLE "options" ALTER COLUMN "size" TYPE decimal(8,8)
```

So how do I give a value scale and precision of 8 on heroku?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres (what is run on Heroku) shoudln't need both precision and scale if they are identical.

Precision is the total number of significant digits

Scale is the number of digits to the right of the DP.

Therefore by setting 8 and 8. This means that it must be 8 digits in total and 8 digits to the right of the DP. Hence why the error - you couldn't have anything greater than 1. 
If you're wanting 8 digits either side of the DP use precision as 16 and scale as 8. If you're just wanting 8 total digits use precision = 8 only.

More info [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL)

Comment: O I see, cheers. Strange how it runs locally. Heroku must be much more strict.

Comment: @Smickie Is this perhaps because your development environment runs SQLite, or another non-Postgresql database? The strictness may be a result of the specific database.